# How to take the first column from the output table under specific conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi

How to run sudo arp-scan and then convert the output into an array such as ['1', '2', ...]
arp-scan doesn't run with subprocess but runs with os.system
The source code of subprocess:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import pandas as pd
def run_process(exe):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        return_code = proc.poll()
        char = proc.stdout.read(1)

        if return_code is not None and len(char) == 0:
            break
        yield char.decode('utf-8')
        
text = ''
for char in run_process('sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet| awk "{print $1}"|tail -n +3|head -n -2'.split()):
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    text += char
```

The output of the subprocess:

```
arp-scan: unrecognized option '--localnet|'
Usage: arp-scan [options] [hosts...]

Target hosts must be specified on the command line unless the --file option is
given, in which case the targets are read from the specified file instead, or
the --localnet option is used, in which case the targets are generated from
the network interface IP address and netmask.

You will need to be root, or arp-scan must be SUID root, in order to run
arp-scan, because the functions that it uses to read and write packets
require root privilege.

The target hosts can be specified as IP addresses or hostnames. You can also
specify the target as IPnetwork/bits (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24) to specify all hosts
in the given network (network and broadcast addresses included), or
IPstart-IPend (e.g. 192.168.1.3-192.168.1.27) to specify all hosts in the
inclusive range, or IPnetwork:NetMask (e.g. 192.168.1.0:255.255.255.0) to
specify all hosts in the given network and mask.

These different options for specifying target hosts may be used both on the
command line, and also in the file specified with the --file option.

use "arp-scan --help" for detailed information on the available options.

Report bugs or send suggestions at https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan
See the arp-scan homepage at https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan
```

It works when i just use sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet but i need the output to be exactly the same as down below:

The source code of the os.sytem along with its output:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time as time
import subprocess
import sys
while True:
   all_function = os.system("sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet| awk '{print $1}'|tail -n +3|head -n -2")
   time.sleep(5)
```

Its output:

```
192.168.50.150
192.168.50.194
```

Comment: Show your pandas code.

Comment: `os.system()` doesn't return the output to Python, it prints it on the screen. Use `subprocess.Popen()` if you want to process the output.

Comment: Importing pandas doesn't actually do anything with pandas. You need to create a dataframe somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this code could be useful:

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import pandas as pd

def to_tabular(text):
        header = text.split('\n')[0]
        columns = [c.strip() for c in header.split('  ') if c != '']
        columns_idx = [header.index(c) for c in columns] + [None, ]

        lines = [l for l in text.split('\n')[1:] if l.strip() != '']
        all_files = []
        for line in lines:
            file = {}
            for column, start_idx, end_idx in zip(columns, columns_idx[:-1], columns_idx[1:]):
                file[column] = line[start_idx:end_idx].strip()
            all_files.append(file)
        return all_files
    
def run_process(exe):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        # returns None while subprocess is running
        return_code = proc.poll()
        char = proc.stdout.read(1)

        if return_code is not None and len(char) == 0:
            break
        yield char.decode('utf-8')
        
text = ''
for char in run_process('sudo arp'.split()):
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    text += char
    
# you have to modify your text file
# in order to reflect the sample below
text = """Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.188.1         3c-3f-12-fc-a7-ed     dynamic  
192.168.188.53        00-2b-00-80-d0-9c     dynamic
239.255.102.18        01-00-5e-ff-66-12     static
239.255.255.250       00-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       00-00-ff-ff-ff-ff     static"""
    
data = to_tabular(text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: I would like to thank you for your support.. Now, i'm trying an another code but it gives me an output that i couldn't solve it.. The question is now replaced with the new one.. Hope you can check it out

Comment: I posted a new question explaining my issue now with the code. I would be grateful if you can check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71211678/how-to-take-the-output-and-make-it-as-an-array-in-python

Comment: @YossefAyman looks like that you missed a space after the `--localnet` param and the `|`